# How to delete all files in a directory with only a single line?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file that allows me to delete all the files in a specific folder which contains only one line. I can count the lines, but then I cannot use it to delete those files.

Can you please help?

Comment: Post the code you've wrote to do exactly the task you've outlined, and fully explain what issues you're facing in running it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need a batch file like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\Temp\*" /A-D-H /B 2^>nul') do call :DeleteFile "C:\Temp\%%I"
endlocal
goto :EOF

:DeleteFile
for /F "usebackq skip=1 eol=" %%J in (%1) do goto :EOF
del /F %1
goto :EOF
```

The first **FOR** executes in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` in background the command line

```
dir "C:\Temp\*" /A-D-H /B 2>nul
```

The command **DIR** lists to **STDOUT** of separate command process

- the file names of all **non-hidden files** in specified directory `C:\Temp` because of `/A-D-H`
- in bare format with just file name and file extension because of `/B`
- matching the simple wildcard pattern `*`.

**DIR** outputs an error message to **STDERR** redirected with `2>nul` to device **NUL** to suppress it if no directory entry is found matching these requirements.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** captures everything output to **STDOUT** of separate command process and process the captured text line by line.

Empty lines are ignored by **FOR** which do not occur here except no matching file name was found by **DIR**.

**FOR** ignores by default on using `/F` all lines starting with a semicolon. A file name without path can start with `;` and therefore `eol=|` is used to redefine the end of line character to a vertical bar which a file name cannot contain.

**FOR** splits up a line by default into substrings (tokens) using space/tab as delimiters and assigns just first space/tab delimited string to specified loop variable `I`. This line splitting behavior is disabled by `delims=` which defines an empty list of delimiters.

So the entire file name is assigned to loop variable `I` which is concatenated with specified folder path to a full qualified file name and passed to subroutine `DeleteFile`.

The command **FOR** in subroutine `DeleteFile` processes the lines in the file of which full qualified file name is passed in double quotes to the subroutine.

The **FOR** option `usebackq` is needed because of full qualified file name in double quotes should not be interpreted as string to process by **FOR**, but as file name of which lines should be processed by **FOR**.

The **FOR** option `skip=1` is used to always skip the first line of the specified file.

The **FOR** option `eol=` defines no end of line character which is required to avoid that a line starting with `;` is ignored by **FOR**.

Normal space and horizontal tab are kept as delimiters as defined by default.

So **FOR** opens the file and skips the first line independent on what this line contains. Then it processes the remaining lines with skipping empty lines and lines containing only spaces/tabs. On a line after first line containing a character not being a normal space or horizontal tab the command `goto :EOF` is executed resulting in exiting the **FOR** loop and the subroutine `DeleteFile`.

For that reason the command **DEL** after the **FOR** loop is executed only if the file does not contain any line at all, or just one line, or one line at top and just multiple empty or blank lines below.

After deletion of the file the subroutine is exited and batch file execution continues on first **FOR** with next file name.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)